# Assets.car and AppIcons in localized folder after building archive

Tags: ios, localization

Summary:
Assets.car and AppIcons in localized folder after building archive.

Steps to Reproduce:
Really, not sure how to repeat it.
I assume that the bug in localization options.
However, prerequisites.

1. I have a project with two localizations English and Russian.
2. I have many localized files, most of them are .strings.
3. Also I have LocalizedInterfaces.xsassets. ( en.lproj/LocalizedInterfaces.xsassets and ru.lproj/LocalizedInterfaces.xsassets )
4. Info.plist CFBundleDevelopmentRegion has value 'en'.

Expected Results:
Everything works fine.
App.app/en.lproj and App.app/ru.lproj contains only .strings files.

Answer (score 0):

I changed order of AppIcons.xcassets and Interfaces.xcassets in copy bundle resources phase.

So, the corner stone in this issue is an order in copy bundle resources phase.

Yes, I know that Xcode warns about resource localization ( assets localization ).

Explanation:

1. LocalizedInterfaces.xcassets are above all other assets in copy bundle resources phase.
2. In this case all assets has default folder as 'App.app/en.lproj' not 'App.app'
3. Changing order of assets by moving down ( to the end of list ) in copy bundle resources phase solve issue.

If you have my issue ( your app icons somehow disappear, but everything fine ) look at order.
All localized assets should be at the end of copy bundle resources list.

Tested on Xcode 8.3.3, hope Xcode 9 have normal localization for assets.